# How to handle loss of connection in python?

Tags: python, python-requests, request

Im working with requesting some data from API server.

```
res=requests.get(path=HTTPBasicAuth(user,password)
```

im trying to test different cases.

1. Permanent connection loss > was solved with ConnectionError exception.
2. Sudden loss : if i lost connection in the middle of requests

How would i handle the second case? the try-except is not working.

Comment: Can't you use `timeout` for your second case? The get request will look like this `requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/', timeout=10)`. It waits for 10 seconds and then raises a `Timeout` exception if no response is received.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter, Retry` and then assign the adapter to a `Session()` like this

```
from requests import Session
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter, Retry
session = Session()
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=Retry(total=10, backoff_factor=0.5))
session.mount('https://', adapter)
session.mount('http://', adapter)
session.get(...)
```